# How to solve the error for import torch on macOs?

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, torch

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import torch

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/__init__.py:202, in <module>
    200     if USE_GLOBAL_DEPS:
    201         _load_global_deps()
--> 202     from torch._C import *  # noqa: F403
    204 # Appease the type checker; ordinarily this binding is inserted by the
    205 # torch._C module initialization code in C
    206 if TYPE_CHECKING:

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/../.dylibs/libomp.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.dylib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/../.dylibs/libomp.dylib: cannot load 'libomp.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/../.dylibs/libomp.dylib: cannot load 'libomp.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
```

This is the error I'm getting on MacOs while working on Jupyter Notebook. I've installed Pytorch using the command "pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio", and it showed it's been installed successfully. I tried to install Anaconda, but the Anaconda installation failed, so, installed torch using pip3.

What could be the reason?
How can I solve this?

I'm trying and expecting to resolve this error.

Comment: See discussion here about openblas vs accelerate: https://github.com/conda-forge/pytorch-cpu-feedstock/pull/88#issuecomment-1657479162

Answer (score 0):

Check your interpreter (The python version you are using at the moment).

To check the Python version in your Jupyter notebook, first import the python_version function with “ from platform import python_version “. Then call the function python_version() that returns a string with the version number running in your Jupyter notebook such as ("3.7. 11") <- example.

Then check if the version of python you are using is the same as the version given during this operation.